# How to close show unsaved changes in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have saved the file,but the plus sign is still showing.
How to close it?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a GitGutter icon. If that's the case, you can only get that to go away by committing the file. Alternatively it is some other package doing it. Sublime has no behaviour to show you changes in the gutter natively.

Comment: Thank you! Gitgutter is the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the "Escape" key on your keyboard causes it to disappear.